# "This might occur when a male and female horse see each other." — Why is it correct to use the singular "horse" with the plural "see" here?

Tags: difference, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number, conjunction-reduction

an excerpt from the book "Walking the Way of the Horse", page 111:

> ... horses can use their front legs and hooves to strike at other horses. This might occur when two horses meet for the first time or when a male and female horse see each other when the female is in "heat".

the phrase the grammar of which I don't understand:
**(1)** *This might occur ... when a male and female **horse** see each other ...*

The general rule (as I see it) says:
*The horse see**s** well at nighttime*. — correct
*The horse see well at nighttime*. — incorrect
*Horse**s** see well at nighttime*. — correct
*Horse**s** see**s** well at nighttime*. — incorrect

Since (1) violates this rule, why is it correct to use "*horse see*" in it?

---

my variant:
**(2)** *This might occur ... when male and female **horses** see each other ...*

Is (2) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what's the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: see well at nighttime is not idiomatic. At night is. It's because there are two horses as nouns, so the verb is plural. compare: When a horse sees another horse.

Comment: Hint: It is not *one single* male and female horse.

Comment: Why would heat be in quotes?  Strange

Comment: @Fattie because it's a slang term I suppose.

Comment: When a boy and girl see each other...

Comment: @Lambie: What's wrong with "see well at nighttime"? It's virtually the same as the example [in the dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nighttime)...

Comment: @tgdavies hmm; that's not a slang term.  For example "horse" is not a slang word; sure "Equus ferus caballus" (or something) is the let's say scientific term but horse is just a word.  Sure, heat is a "makes schoolboys snicker" word, but so is toilet, sex, breasts, underpants etc.  It's not slang and I don't see it marked as slang in any dictionary.

Comment: @psmears See well at night. Nightime is not a good time to nap.

Comment: @Lambie: Eh? "See well at night" works too, granted, but what's the problem with "see well at nighttime"? It sounds fine to me, and is no different from the example given in the dictionary - unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: @Fattie: I agree, but perhaps to someone with more veterinary training "in heat" might seem like a slang term (compared to, say, "in oestrus"...)

Comment: @psmears Personally, "see well at nightime" just seems corny to me. "See well at night": About 986,000 results (0.27 seconds) "see well at nighttime" About 54,200 results (0.19 seconds)

Comment: @Lambie: You're entitled to your opinion on style, of course, and the expression is indeed less common - but I don't think it's really justified to claim it's "not idiomatic" when examples that are very close are given in dictionaries including Cambridge (I linked above), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nighttime) & [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/nighttime)...

Comment: @psmears If you look carefully at all those sentences under nighttime in the Cambridge Dictionary, you will see that there is only one instance where nighttime is used like "see at nighttime". Suffice it to say, the others all sound right. By the way, my opinion here is not something one would find in a dictionary. It is used adjectively and as a noun, but only one instance of: She saves her most powerful stories for around the hearth *at nighttime*. That sounds fine. Question: Do you see well at nighttime? I would **never** say that. Truthfully, would you?

Comment: I've lost track of the argument, but "see well at nighttime" is wrong.  nighttime does not mean "it is dark", it's a social grouping of parts of the day, rather like mentioning "brunch".  "night" means dark.  there are no "nighttime vision goggles".

Comment: @Fattie: ...and yet... the [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nighttime)... literally has an example about seeing "at nighttime"! _It can be lit by batteries so that at nighttime and during fog it can be seen._ It may not be what _you_ would say (maybe it's a BrE vs AmE thing?), but claiming that it's outright "wrong" is... not backed up by the evidence.

Comment: I found two examples in a crap online dictionary, https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nighttime Nightime is (as I say) used to mean a social-construction

Comment: sorry our posts crossed.  PS, you show a fair example, I'm afraid for me the evidence is overwhelmingly the other way

Comment: @Fattie I should have said "informal, in the context of a book about horses"

Comment: makes sense - you're right

Answer (score 22):

It's a slightly awkward phrasing.

The noun phrase that governs the verb has a plural meaning.  The author means "a male horse and a female horse"  This coordination of two singular nouns results in a noun phrase that is plural.

But the author wanted to avoid the repetition, so has reduced this to "a male and female horse".  I say it is slightly awkward, since it could be read as a coordination of adjectives, modifying a singular noun.  Context tells us that that is wrong, and that the meaning is plural. So there is no problem in understanding.

Your variant with "Horses" is a good choice, and avoids the awkwardness. But it slightly changes the meaning. "A male horse and a female horse" means one of each sex. But "male and female horses" could mean one or many of each sex.

This is just a situation in which there is no perfect phrasing: "Precise, grammatically smooth, not repetitious: pick two"

Comment: Are the following sentences correct?: i) _A blue and red pencil were on the table_. ii) _There were a blue and red pencil on the table_. iii) _My and your pencil were on this table_. Thanks.

Comment: yes

Comment: @Loviii The "one noun, two adjectives" intent of "a male and female horse" could have been helped by an extra "a": "a male and a female horse." In this case we were unlikely to have thought it meant one horse that was simultaneously male and female, but in some other context the confusion would be possible: "A black and [a] white cat had a fight on my fence last night."

Comment: @Loviii Please stop making all these little changes to your questions as you go along.  It is unfair to everyone. A man and a woman walk here everyday. [two people] A man walks here with a woman everyday. A blue pencil and a red one **were** on the table. There was a red pencil and a blue pencil on the table. "a" cannot take a plural unless there are two of the same thing and this is spelled out.

Comment: @Lambie You wrote: "Please stop making all these little changes to your questions as you go along. It is unfair to everyone." Unfortunately, I couldn't understand it. What does "_these little changes to your question_" mean? Why is it unfair to everyone? Could you please explain to me what you meant?

Comment: Please discuss that in Chat, not in comments

Comment: The phrasing "male and female horses see each other" (if we pretend for a second to forget the context of this discussion) is actually more ambiguous. The sentence could be construed to mean "male horses see each other and female horses see each other", not mixed! E.g. "male athletes and female athletes have their own rooms", while poorly phrased,  would probably be understood to *each* having their own room.

Comment: Hey James what about ".. when two horses see each other ..".  I've never really known how to handle these two-to-one writing situations. I usually justy give up and assume it's understandable in context.

Comment: "When two horses" loses the "male meets female" aspect.  I don't think there is a perfect solution here.  Just a choice of compromise.  And, as in this case, there isn't any real difficulty with "a male and female horse meet each other"

Comment: Tell me please whether "_A blue and a red pencil**s** were on the table._" is also correct or not?

Comment: "When two horses of opposite sex see each other" communicates the meaning, I think

Comment: It also communicates the same meaning, but it is no clearer. @gus

Comment: @Lembie It doesn't look like Loviii has made any changes to their question at all

Comment: @Loviii no, the full sentence would be "a blue [pencil] and [a] red pencil were on the table". You can leave out unnecessary words (the ones in brackets), but you don't change things to plural because the sentence structure stays the same.

Answer (score 7):

To basically restate [James K's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/347576) in slightly different (maybe hopefully clearer?) terms:

---

This is a case of [ellipsis](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/260/ellipsis).  The full phrase without ellipsis would look like this:

> "… when **a male horse and a female horse** see each other …"

There are two horses.  Each horse is singular, and so takes a singular article.  But *both* of these horses are the subject of the verb, so the verb is plural.

However, repeating the word "horse" like this is somewhat awkward, and also unnecessary.  We can simply leave the first "horse" out of the sentence, with the reader being able to mentally fill it in based on the surrounding context:

> "… when **a male and a female horse** see each other …"

Here there are *still* two horses, each of them singular, but both of them together acting as the subject of a plural verb.

---

Where I personally disagree with the book's author slightly is that I would *not* also leave out the "a" before "female".

I would not do so in speech (where "and a" is pretty much pronounced like a single word anyway), and so would also not do it in writing.  The English language is full of articles, conjunctions, preprositions and other similar short words like these that take no stress when spoken and just fall in the gaps between the other words.  They are so short that omitting them saves basically no time, and naturally repeated so often that repeating them is not unusual or awkward at all.

Besides that, the phrase "a male and female horse" could be alternatively parsed as referring to a single horse that is somehow both male and female at the same time.  Obviously that's not the intended meaning in the given context, but just having to consider and reject that parsing is needlessly jarring.  Leaving in the second article rules out this alternative parsing.

All that said, however, the author's version is still clear and understandable enough in its context.  In fact, I probably would not have even noticed the missing "a" when reading it if your question hadn't focused on that particular phrase.

---

**Ps.** Your version with "male and female horses" is also correct, but less precise: it allows for (and even implicitly suggests) the possibility that there may be more than one male horse and more than one female horse involved.  The author clearly intended there to be only one of each, so they chose to use two singular subjects instead.

By the way, "male and female horses" is technically *also* elliptic; the full phrase without ellipsis would be "male horses and female horses".

For what it's worth, "a male horse and a female" would technically also be correct; when a repeated word can be omitted, we can usually choose either one of the repetitions to leave out.  However, this version sounds slightly more awkward to my ear, perhaps because adjectives in English normally come before the nouns they refer to, and so having "female" refer backwards to the word "horse" before it feels a bit awkward.  It almost calls for a placeholder like "a male horse and a female one", although, at least to my ear, that's not quite necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, native speakers don't really think too hard about this, so it may be hard for us to determine the rule.  I am not a language expert, but am a native speaker.

I believe this is really a shortened version of

"This may happen when a male ***horse*** and a female horse see each other..."

I believe all native English speakers will confirm the following are correct...

"This may happen when two male horses and a female horse see each other..."

Or

"This may happen when a male and two female horses see each other..."

Notice that there could be some confusion dealing with plural phrases.  Subject-verb agreement is different than adjective-noun agreement.

For example, "A male and female horse ***are*** happier together."

Verses "A male horse ***is*** happy alone."

The phrase "a male and female horse" is a plural noun phrase.  But "female horse" is a singular noun.

Answer (score 0):

It's one male horse,
and one female horse.
The two together are plural.

Makes perfect sense to me

Comment: You are correct, but this doesn't add anything new to the existing answers. Please read through those before giving your own answer.